# Alternative to Hash Map for Small Data set in C

Tags: c, performance, hashmap

I am currently working on a command line interface for a [particle simulator](http://code.google.com/p/arcsim/). Its parser takes reads input in the following format:

[command] [argument]* (-[flag] [flag argument]*)*

Currently, the command is sent through a conditional block, compared to various known commands and its corresponding data packet is sent to the matching function. This, however, seems clunky, inefficient and inelegant.

I am thinking about using a hashmap instead, with a string representation of a command as the key and a function pointer as the value. The function referenced would then be sent a data packet containing arguments, flags, etc.

Is a hash map overkill in this situation? Does the extra infrastructure required to implement one outweigh the potential benefits? I am aiming for speed, elegance, function, and, since this is an open-source project, extensibility.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe an ordered map would suffice, since you're probably not going to have millions of cases or call the parser in a tight loop. However, since neither of those are entirely trivial to write, perhaps chose a structure that your compiler already ships.

Comment: I think you have to keep in mind that the arguments are evaluated only on startup, you have no chance to make it a bottleneck for speed. A hashmap seems to be an enough elegant solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the [Ternary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree). It has good performnce, efficient use of storage; and you don't need a hash function or a collision strategy.

The linked Bentley/Sedgwick article is a very thorough-yet-readable explanation of the accompanying C source.

I've been using a TST for name-lookup in the past 3 versions of my postscript interpreter. The only changes that have been needed have been due to changes in memory management. [Here's a version](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/GIN9ZtwGOFg/LIkK9YHTxNwJ) I modified (lightly) to use explicit pointers. I use yet another version in my [postscript interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/list), any of the xpost2*.zip versions, in the file core.c, which uses byte-offsets for pointers (have to be added to the user-memory byte-pointer to yield a *real* pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Speed gained will probably be minimal, but you could hash the command to convert it to a number and then use a switch statement.  Faster than a hash map.